# Android Google play games services and libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I published app in google play console and now i want add Google play games services to make leaderboard. I added new game in console and join my already published game.

My problem is that I still get this error:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
                  at com.jdstudio.flappyplane.AndroidLauncher.onActivityResult(AndroidLauncher.java:123)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6241)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3591)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3638)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

I know that sha-1 key have to be same in my app so I added signin config in android studio. Packages names are also the same.

Comment: Hi, can you show us your Google Play Games services integration ?

Comment: Problem is solved. I cerate new app in google developer console and it is working now, but I don`t know how to remove old app.